# How to get posts from a private community on google+?

Tags: api, google-plus

I have to develop an application (in any language) which gets informations in several posts on Google+, in a private community. I found that Google API didn't even have this feature for public communities...

So my question is : Is it even possible to get those informations in any other way than collecting it manually from an internet browser ? (In other words, collecting it for example just by clicking on a button, on my application. I suppose that authentication would be the great problem.)

Thank you in advance ! 
(Excuse me if I made some english mistakes, I'm not a native english speaker ^^)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that as of april 2016 google still hasnt added a way to read posts from a community which i find lacking too.
One option which may be impractical (and useless in public communities) is to read the posts in the stream of all members that is also part of a google apps domain, using the G+ domains api, and manually filter those posted to the community members.
 It requires you read all post by all community members to build the entire posts list.

Note that new posts sometimes take half hour to show up with the api. Lame yes. Works yes.

Another way is to use the G+ community meter Chrome extension which likely gathers the statistics you need, or do something similar to what that extension does. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/community-meter/gnhdadjbiljclldiiadlffpakeihdflb

Comment: Except for private posts which are not available through the API regardless.

Comment: The vast majority of Google+ API questions are for standard Google account.

Comment: In the worst case create a gapps domain with one user and make it member of the communities. This will cost you at most $50 yearly (if you dont use it for other projects) i updated my answer with this info.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/reading) "The Google+ Domains API only permits reading posts by people in the same Google Apps domain as the user, and comments on those posts."

Comment: Yes. I tested this and you are right. Only posts from domain members show up in the api. Im leaving the answer as its still useful for domain scenarios

Comment: @ZigMandel Hey thanks for sharing. I tried to read the posts by different members but couldn't. API is only returning the posts posted by the given(impersonated) user.